# VK_ERROR_SURFACE_LOST_KHR while executing vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR()

Tags: vulkan

I met some problem while learning Vulkan. I followed Vulkan Coockbook but I failed on executing vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR(), it returned VK_ERROR_SURFACE_LOST_KHR. I have no idea what the wrong is with my code.

```
    CyApplication::CyApplication(void) {
#ifdef _WIN32
        VulkanLibrary = LoadLibrary(L"vulkan-1.dll");
#elif defined __linux
        VulkanLibrary = dlopen("libvulkan.so.1", RTLD_NOW);
#endif
        if (VulkanLibrary == nullptr) {
            throw std::runtime_error("");
        }

#ifdef _WIN32
        vkGetInstanceProcAddr = (PFN_vkGetInstanceProcAddr)GetProcAddress(VulkanLibrary, "vkGetInstanceProcAddr");
#elif defined __linux
        vkGetInstanceProcAddr = (PFN_vkGetInstanceProcAddr)dlsym(VulkanLibrary, "vkGetInstanceProcAddr");
#endif

        // Load global functions
        vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties = (PFN_vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(nullptr, "vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties");
        vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties = (PFN_vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(nullptr, "vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties");
        vkCreateInstance = (PFN_vkCreateInstance)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(nullptr, "vkCreateInstance");

        // Create instance
        desiredInstanceExtensions.emplace_back(VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME);
        desiredInstanceExtensions.emplace_back(
#ifdef VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR
            VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME
#elif defined VK_USE_PLATFORM_XLIB_KHR
            VK_KHR_XLIB_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME
#elif defined VK_USE_PLATFORM_XCB_KHR
            VK_KHR_XCB_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME
#endif
        );

        applicationInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
        applicationInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        applicationInfo.pApplicationName = "Cygine";
        applicationInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
        applicationInfo.pEngineName = "Cygine";
        applicationInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
        applicationInfo.apiVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);

        instanceCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
        instanceCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        instanceCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        instanceCreateInfo.pApplicationInfo = &applicationInfo;
        instanceCreateInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
        instanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = nullptr;
        instanceCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(desiredInstanceExtensions.size());
        instanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = desiredInstanceExtensions.data();

        if (vkCreateInstance(&instanceCreateInfo, nullptr, &instance)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create the Vulkan instance.");
        }

        loadInstanceLevelFunctions();

        // Create presentation surface
#ifdef VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR
        wndParams.HInstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);

        WNDCLASSEX window_class = {
              sizeof(WNDCLASSEX),             // UINT         cbSize
                                                // Win 3.x
              CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,          // UINT         style
              WindowProcedure,                  // WNDPROC      lpfnWndProc
              0,                                // int          cbClsExtra
              0,                                // int          cbWndExtra
              wndParams.HInstance,           // HINSTANCE    hInstance
              nullptr,                          // HICON        hIcon
              LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW), // HCURSOR      hCursor
              (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1),       // HBRUSH       hbrBackground
              nullptr,                          // LPCSTR       lpszMenuName
              L"CygineWindow",                  // LPCSTR       lpszClassName
                                                // Win 4.0
              nullptr                           // HICON        hIconSm
        };

        if (!RegisterClassEx(&window_class)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("WSL");
        }

        wndParams.Hwnd = CreateWindow(L"CyApplicationWindow",
            L"CyApplication",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            (HWND)nullptr,
            (HMENU)nullptr,
            wndParams.HInstance,
            (LPVOID)nullptr);

        if (wndParams.Hwnd = nullptr) {
            throw std::runtime_error("");
        }

        surfaceCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WIN32_SURFACE_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
        surfaceCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        surfaceCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        surfaceCreateInfo.hinstance = wndParams.HInstance;
        surfaceCreateInfo.hwnd = wndParams.Hwnd;

        ShowWindow(wndParams.Hwnd, SW_SHOW);

        VkResult result = vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR(instance, &surfaceCreateInfo, nullptr, &surface);

        if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
#elif defined VK_USE_PLATFORM_XLIB_KHR
        wndParams.dpy = XOpenDisplay();
        wndParams.window = XCreateWindow(nullptr);

        surfaceCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_XLIB_SURFACE_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
        surfaceCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        surfaceCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        surfaceCreateInfo.hinstance = wndParams.dpy;
        surfaceCreateInfo.hwnd = wndParams.window;

        VkResult result = vkCreateXlibSurfaceKHR(instance, &surfaceCreateInfo, nullptr, &surface);

        if (result != VK_SUCCESS || surface == VK_NULL_HANDLE) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
#elif defined VK_USE_PLATFORM_XCB_KHR
        wndParams.connect = xcb_connect();
        wndParams.window = xcb_generate_id(nullptr);

        surfaceCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_XLIB_SURFACE_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
        surfaceCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        surfaceCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        surfaceCreateInfo.hinstance = wndParams.dpy;
        surfaceCreateInfo.hwnd = wndParams.window;

        VkResult result = vkCreateXcbSurfaceKHR(instance, &surfaceCreateInfo, nullptr, &surface);

        if (result != VK_SUCCESS || surface == VK_NULL_HANDLE) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
#endif

        // Select physical device
        desiredPhysicalDeviceExtensions.emplace_back(VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME);
        getAvailablePhysicalDevices();
        do {
            fmt::print("Select a physical device that Cygine will run on: ");
            std::cin >> selectedPhysicalDeviceID;
        } while (selectedPhysicalDeviceID >= availablePhysicalDevicesCount);

        physicalDevice = availablePhysicalDevices[selectedPhysicalDeviceID];
        getAvailablePhysicalDeviceExtensions(physicalDevice);
        

        // Create logical device
        getPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(availablePhysicalDevices[selectedPhysicalDeviceID]);
        selectQueueFamily(VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT | VK_QUEUE_COMPUTE_BIT);

        queueCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
        queueCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        queueCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        queueCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndex = queueFamilyIndex;
        queueCreateInfo.queueCount = 1;
        float queuePriority = 1.0f;
        queueCreateInfo.pQueuePriorities = &queuePriority;

        deviceCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
        deviceCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        deviceCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        deviceCreateInfo.queueCreateInfoCount = /*static_cast<uint32_t>(queueCreateInfos.size())*/ 1;
        deviceCreateInfo.pQueueCreateInfos = /*queueCreateInfos.data()*/ &queueCreateInfo;
        deviceCreateInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
        deviceCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = nullptr;
        deviceCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(desiredPhysicalDeviceExtensions.size());
        deviceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = desiredPhysicalDeviceExtensions.data();
        deviceCreateInfo.pEnabledFeatures = &desiredDeviceFeatures;

        if (vkCreateDevice(physicalDevice, &deviceCreateInfo, nullptr, &device) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to create logical device!");
        }

        loadDeviceLevelFunctions();

        // Create presentation surface

        /*
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
        GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Window Title", NULL, NULL);

        if (glfwCreateWindowSurface(instance, window, nullptr, &surface))
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to create");
            */

        getSurfaceCapabilities();
        fmt::print("Min Image Count: {}\n", surfaceCapabilities.minImageCount);

    }
} // CygineApplicationAbstractions
```

Above is a part of my code. Have to say cooking Vulkan is really trivial ... Does any one have an idea? Hope you can solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Which of the paths cause the problem? WIN32, Xlib, or XCB?

Comment: You should show the implementation of your `getSurfaceCapabilities()`.

Comment: I think your window class name does not match in `CreateWindow` with the one in `WNDCLASSEX`.

Comment: Thank you @krOoze, I changed the window class name to the same but the problem still exists. It is on WIN32.

Comment: The implementation of getSufaceCapabilities() is below. But I just encapsulated it, I have no idea what problem there could be.
void CyApplication::getSurfaceCapabilities(void) {
  VkResult result = vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR(physicalDevice, surface, &surfaceCapabilities);
  if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
   fmt::print("{}", result);
   throw std::runtime_error("Could not get capabilities of the surface.");
  }
 }

Answer (score 2):

```
if (wndParams.Hwnd = nullptr) {
```

You assign `nullptr` to `Hwnd`, so the surface is invalid when you query it.